# php DOM element value is not human readable as the content is non English

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to get html content of some remote site. I am using following php script but the output by this script is full of non-readable characters. I have no idea why it should behave like this. FYI, I am using chrome browser latest for my testing.

**Script:**

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.sandesh.com/article.aspx?newsid=115627";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
//echo $output;
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
@$DOM->loadHTML($output);
//get all H1
$items = $DOM -> getElementById('lblNews');
echo  $DOM -> getElementById('lblNews')->tagName;

echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /></head><body><span>". $items -> nodeValue ."</span". "<br/></body></html>";

//display all H1 text
/*
for ($i = 0; $i < $items -> length; $i++) {
    echo $items -> item($i) -> nodeValue . "<br/>";
}*/
?>
```

Output:

```
span Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂµÃ Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¦Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ²Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â€, Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾. Ã Â«Â¨Ã Â«Â¨ Ã ÂªÂ­Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«Â‹ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ­Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ§Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ²Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ–Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂšÃ Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ£Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂµÃ Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂˆÃ ÂªÂ¡Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¦ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂŸÃ Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ® Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ˜Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«Â‹ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â€, Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ§ Ã ÂªÂšÃ Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂˆ Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ­Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¦Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¯ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ• Ã ÂªÂ­Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂŸÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¯ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ· Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¨ Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ³Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¯ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¦Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¦Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚. Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ  Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ²Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ²Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂƒÃ ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ£Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ­Ã Â«ÂˆÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ²Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ• Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ²Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ• Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¦ Ã ÂªÂœ Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¤ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«Â€. Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¦ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ‰Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¦Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¦ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¦Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ«Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂˆÃ ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«ÂŒÃ ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ³ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡. Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂŸÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¯ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ• Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ˜ (Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂÃ ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂÃ ÂªÂ¸)Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ® Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ£Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂµÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡, Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂµÃ Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂˆÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ® Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂˆ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡. Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ§Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¦Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¯ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¤ Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã ÂªÂˆ Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ® Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‹ Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ£Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂµÃ Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡. Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ« Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ  Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¤ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¦ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂŸÃ Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂµÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚. Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ® Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ§Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¤ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂµÃ Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ­Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡. Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¦Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ§ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‹ Ã ÂªÂ˜Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ® Ã Â«Â§.Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â  Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ²Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ²Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂƒÃ ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ£Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¦Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ«Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã ÂªÂ¦Ã ÂªÂ²Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ³ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã Â«Â¨.Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â  Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ³Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ‡Ã ÂªÂŸÃ Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿ Ã ÂªÂ—Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂª Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ³Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ²Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ“Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¸ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¥ Ã ÂªÂ§Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«Â€ Ã Â«Â©.Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â  Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ³Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¤ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¶Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ²Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ“ Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ§Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«Â€, Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ£Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ® Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ³ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã Â«Âª.Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â  Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ­Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ²Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ˜Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ• Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«Â€ Ã Â«Â«.Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â  Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ²Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ«Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¬Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ‡Ã ÂªÂŸÃ Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ· Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡, Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã Â«Â¨Ã Â«Â©Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¦Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂšÃ Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ£Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡. Â Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ­Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ·Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂŸÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ³Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ†Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡. Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ…Ã ÂªÂ§Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¦ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂŸÃ Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ˜ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‹ Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂµ Ã ÂªÂ¨ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«Â‚Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡. Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ²Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂŸ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ³Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‹ Ã ÂªÂ«Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¶. Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¦Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂœÃ ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¯ Ã ÂªÂ·Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂšÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«Â‡. Ã ÂªÂ®Ã Â«Â‡Ã ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¶Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ–Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂŸÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â€, Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚ Ã ÂªÂ•Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂˆ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂªÃ Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¸ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂŸÃ Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«ÂˆÃ ÂªÂ¯Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ° Ã ÂªÂ›Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ‚, Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ£ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂŸÃ Â«Â€ Ã ÂªÂ¹Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â‡ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«ÂÃ ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ¸Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¨ Ã ÂªÂªÃ ÂªÂ¹Ã Â«Â‹Ã ÂªÂ‚Ã ÂªÂšÃ ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂµÃ ÂªÂ¾ Ã ÂªÂ®Ã ÂªÂ¾Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã Â«Â‹ Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã ÂªÂ¥Ã Â«Â€. Â - Ã ÂªÂ¨Ã Â«Â€Ã ÂªÂ¤Ã ÂªÂ¿Ã ÂªÂ¨ Ã ÂªÂ—Ã ÂªÂ¡Ã ÂªÂ•Ã ÂªÂ°Ã Â«Â€
```

**Effect After adding meta tag fot content type:**

[image]

**PasteBin for Expected Output:**

Similar to this pastebin link without first span as we want the content from inside of it.
http://pastebin.com/0fefAnhC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you need to declare this document as a UTF-8 document.

Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to your `<head> </head>`.

Modified Code:

```
$url = "http://www.sandesh.com/article.aspx?newsid=115627";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
//echo $output;
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$output = mb_convert_encoding($output, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 
@$DOM->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$output);
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper
//get all H1
$items = $DOM -> getElementById('lblNews');
echo  $DOM -> getElementById('lblNews')->tagName;

echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head></head><body><span>". $items -> nodeValue ."</span". "<br/></body></html>";
```

Comment: another way is header `header("Content-type:text/html;charset-utf-8");`

Comment: I tried to add header("Content-type:text/html;charset-utf-8"); but not working

Comment: Also I tried adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> to your <head> </head> because I thought that was a problem. But this meta tag is actually getting added in body instead of head. Any idea?

Comment: It should be: `header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');`

Comment: I figured it out, your error is caused by the `DOMDocument`'s handling of UTF-8 code. Add `$output = mb_convert_encoding($output, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");` before the `loadHTML` and add the UTF-8 declaration: to the `loadHTML` function: `@$DOM->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$output);`.

Comment: @VendettaDroid - See above for my edited solution. Note, the header may still be necessary, I only tested this on PHP's command line interpreter.

Comment: @iWizardPro: No it is still showing similar output to what I pasted above. Pastebin for output in your case: http://pastebin.com/yANG4B9Y

Comment: @iWizardPro: Updated question with expected output pastebin for reference.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mKF64put for full code. I tested it in my browser and have confirmed that the code works if you copy it exactly as written.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23182/discussion-between-iwizardpro-and-vendettadroid)